# Beginner AI: Why is the recursive call only acting on the first row of sudoku board?

Tags: java, recursion, backtracking, sudoku

I can provide more code if necessary but I dont think it is. Cell[][] can be thought of as Integer[][]. getCellDomains() goes through rows, col, and 3x3 box to see what is not in those respectively and adds them to a LinkedList. isValid Checks on whether or not this can be placed. I know that these are quite similar and plan to edit them in the future but want to get it running correctly first. Reading in board from csv and filling blanks with zeros.
Example Board:

```
5,7,8,6,9,3,2,1,0
0,9,0,1,0,0,0,5,7
1,0,0,0,7,0,0,3,6
2,8,0,0,0,6,0,0,4
9,6,0,8,0,5,0,2,3
7,0,0,2,0,0,0,9,8
8,3,0,0,5,0,0,0,9
6,2,0,0,0,7,0,8,0
0,0,7,0,0,0,0,6,2
```

QUESTION: Why is my recursive call in forwardCheck terminating after only going through the first row of my sudoku board? I appreciate any and all feedback.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    String sudokuInput = "puzzles/Easy-P2.csv";
    String sudokuOutput = "Easy-P2-Solution.csv";



    SudokuSolver board = new SudokuSolver();
    // Read in data from csv
    board.getData(sudokuInput);
    //backtrack(board.grid);
    forwardCheck(board.grid);


    System.out.println("Final Output: ");
    board.printData(sudokuOutput);


}

public static boolean forwardCheck(Cell[][] board) {
        boolean isEmpty = true;
        int row = -1;
        int col = -1;
        LinkedList<Integer> valueDomain = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {

                if (board[i][j].getValue() == 0) {
                    row = i;
                    col = j;
                    valueDomain = getCellDomains(board, row, col);
                    isEmpty = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!isEmpty) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isEmpty) {
            return true;
        }


        if (valueDomain.size() == 0) {
                backtrack(board);
        } else {
            int valueDomainSize = valueDomain.size();
            Random randomGenerator = new Random();
            int randomIndex = randomGenerator.nextInt(valueDomainSize);
            if (valueDomain.size() == 1) {
                board[row][col].setValue(valueDomain.getFirst());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Setting value of " + valueDomain.get(randomIndex) + " from " + valueDomain);
                if(isValid(board, row, col, valueDomain.get(randomIndex))){
                    board[row][col].setValue(valueDomain.get(randomIndex));
                    forwardCheck(board);

                }
            }
        }
    return false;
    }

private void getData(String filePath) {
    grid = new Cell[boardSize][boardSize];
    Scanner scanIn = null;
    int row = 0;

    try {
        scanIn = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath)));

        while (scanIn.hasNextLine()) {
            String inputLine = scanIn.nextLine();
            String[] inArray = inputLine.split(",");
            for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
                Cell curCell = new Cell();
                if (row == 0 && i == 0){
                    inArray[i] = inArray[i].substring(1);
                }
                //if input is a blank space
                if (inArray[i].equals("?")){
                    curCell.setValue(0);
                    curCell.setChangeFlag(false);
                    grid[row][i] = curCell;
                }
                //else if input is a number
                else{
                    curCell.setValue(Integer.parseInt(inArray[i]));
                    curCell.setChangeFlag(true);
                    grid[row][i] = curCell;
                }

            }
            row++;
        }
        scanIn.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Bad Input: " + e);
        scanIn.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does this have `python` tag in it ?

Comment: Should be fixed now. My mistake, first question I have ever asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
 /**
 * Simple backtrack algorithm with addition of forward checking to reduce
 * wrong paths followed
 * @param board The board object
 * @return returns true when board is complete
 */
    public static boolean forwardCheck(Cell[][] board) {
        LinkedList<Integer> valueDomain = null;

        for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < board.length; col++) {
                if (board[row][col].getValue() != 0) {
                    continue;
                }
                valueDomain = getCellDomains(board, row, col);
                for (int value : valueDomain) {
                    if (isValid(board, row, col, value)) {
                        board[row][col].setValue(value);
                        if (forwardCheck(board)) {
                            return true;
                        }
                        else {
                            board[row][col].setValue(0);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    return true;
    }

/**
 * Get cell domain in order to reduce going down wrong paths
 * @param board The board object
 * @param row The row you would like to check
 * @param col The col you would like to check
 * @return
 */
public static LinkedList<Integer> getCellDomains(Cell[][] board, int row, int col) {
    LinkedList<Integer> domains = new LinkedList<>();

    for (int value = 1; value <= 9; value++) {
        if(!existInRow(board, row, value) && !existInCol(board, col, value) && !existInBox(board, row,col, value)) {
            domains.add(value);

        }
    }
    //System.out.println ("Domain: " + domains.getFirst());
    return domains;
}

/**
 * Check whether or not given value is in row
 * @param board The board object
 * @param row The row you would like to check
 * @param value The value you would like to check
 * @return true if value exist in row
 */
public static boolean existInRow(Cell[][] board, int row, int value) {
    for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
        if (board[row][j].getValue() == value) {

            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Check whether or not given value is in col
 * @param board The board object
 * @param col The col you would like to check
 * @param value The value you would like to check
 * @return true if value exist in col
 */
public static boolean existInCol(Cell[][] board, int col, int value) {
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        if (board[i][col].getValue() == value) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Check whether or not given value is in 3x3 box
 * @param board The board object
 * @param row The row you would like to check
 * @param col The col you would like to check
 * @param value The value you would like to check
 * @return true if value exist in box
 */
public static boolean existInBox(Cell[][] board, int row, int col, int value) {
    int sudokuBox = (int) Math.sqrt(board.length);
    int iBox = row - row % 3;
    int jBox = col - col % 3;

    for (int i = iBox; i < iBox + sudokuBox; i++) {
        for (int j = jBox; j < jBox + sudokuBox; j++) {
            if (board[i][j].getValue() == value) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).